# The how,what and why of directed angles

Tags: geometry

I recently came to know about directed angles.I felt it was a strong convention but didnt understand much of it i understood the basics but I would like to know more about its applications like if we can use sine rule using directed angles and all.Also I would like to know any lookout to when we even use this convention.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why close this interesting question ? It is very thorough ! Why this closing frenzy one sees too frequently ?

Comment: A quick comment: 1) the sine rule is applied on unsigned angles. 2) the concept of "signed angle" has been introduced rather lately, in the mid-19th century (in particular by Chasles). One of its interests is that it allows to unify results that otherwise would be separated in different cases.

Comment: I agree with @JeanMarie . Why the close votes? I think this is a good question.

Comment: See this document : http://www.math.ubbcluj.ro/~didactica/pdfs/2018/didmath2018-03.pdf

Comment: Any lookout to when should i consider using directed angles??